# Problem while calculating entropy using Gibb's relation

Tags: entropy, statistical-mechanics

the question
[homework question from Concepts in thermal physics 2nd edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFY1B.png)

my attempt
[how I approached the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWRNO.jpg)
I am stuck at the marked step, specifically what do I do of Pi multiplied by ln(Z). 
P.S I am having problems formatting the math, hence put pictures.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @stealth225, from your [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWRNO.jpg) to picture you stop at $\sum_i P_iLn(Z)=Ln(Z)\sum_i P_i$ Now do you see the solution?